# Ajax in Wordpress returning 400 bad request and but not sure how to debug further

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to use Ajax to output the data of a page (or anything, for that matter) into a div. The data is based on a list on the page. Although the jQuery function to call the Ajax request appears to work, I am getting a 400 bad request on the console from the Ajax call. How to debug this, as I cannot get any console.log messages from the Ajax callback function

I have a wordpress file that outputs a list of product categories and some jQuery that fires when one of the listed categories is clicked. This jQuery has the Ajax post function to call my enqueued and localized function. This function does not appear to do anything, even a simple console.log, and the :error of the ajax call shows that the error is a 400 bad request. Using WPEngine password protected staging site, it that might make a difference.

```
in functions.php
--------------------
```

```html
--------------------
in funcitons.php
--------------------
        // for displaying products in div on category page
function enqueue_show_products_scripts () {
        // get the javascript file and enqueue it, then ad it to the     wp_print_scripts action
        $script_location = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/includes/js/show_products.js";
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', $script_location, array ('jquery') );
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax', array('url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )) );
    }
    add_action ('wp_print_scripts', 'enqueue_show_products_scripts');

    // this is the function that the Ajax request is running
    function show_products_callback() {
        // Get the request data global $wpdb;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log ("in show_products_callback");
    </script>
    <?php
        // get_the_data
        //echo(get_term_link($_POST['term_id']));
        //get_term_link($_POST['term_id']);
        //get_term_link(680);
        //print_r($_REQUEST);

        die();
    }

    // and this adds the actions on init to register the function with the Ajax and
    add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_show_products', 'show_products_callback' );
    add_action ( 'wp_ajax_show_products', 'show_products_callback' );


    in show_product.js
    ----------------------
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery('#categoryListBox a').click ( function () {
        var term_id_clicked = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        alert ("Clicked " + term_id_clicked );
        jQuery.post  ( {
          url: ajax.url,
          action: 'show_products',
          term_id: term_id_clicked,
          success: function ( data ) {
            console.log (data),
            jQuery('#productBox').html(data)
          },
          error: function (errorThrown) {
            console.log ("errorThrown"),
            console.log (errorThrown)
          }
        }
        );  // end jQuery.ajax
    }); // end jQuery click
    });

    jQuery( document ).ajaxError(function( event, data, settings, exception ) {
        alert( "Triggered ajaxError handler." +event+" "+data+" "+settings+" "+exception);
    });


    in show_all_products_by_category.php
    ---------------------------------
    <div id='categoryListBox'>
    <h3>All products by Category</h3>
    ...
          <ul class="categoryUL">
    <?php
            $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
            foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
            {
                $name = $child_product_cat->name;
                $slug = $child_product_cat->slug;
                $term_id = $child_product_cat->term_id;
    ?>
                <li id='categoryLI-<?= $slug ?>'>
                  <a id='<?= $term_id ?>' href='#'><?=    $child_product_cat->name?></a>
                </li>
    <?php
                // the id is the slug of the subcategory, and the action is performed in the jQuery event
            } // end FOREACH CHILD
    ?>
            </ul>
    ...
    </div>

I keep getting error 400 bad request in the console, but am stumped on how to further debug, as no output from the callback function appears when I echo, alert or console.log.
```

List item

```
in show_product.js
----------------------
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#categoryListBox a').click ( function () {
    var term_id_clicked = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    alert ("Clicked " + term_id_clicked );
    jQuery.post  ( {
      url: ajax.url,
      action: 'show_products',
      term_id: term_id_clicked,
      success: function ( data ) {
        console.log (data),
        jQuery('#productBox').html(data)
      },
      error: function (errorThrown) {
        console.log ("errorThrown"),
        console.log (errorThrown)
      }
    }
    );  // end jQuery.ajax
}); // end jQuery click
});

jQuery( document ).ajaxError(function( event, data, settings, exception ) {
    alert( "Triggered ajaxError handler." +event+" "+data+" "+settings+" "+exception);
});


in show_all_products_by_category.php
---------------------------------
<div id='categoryListBox'>
<h3>All products by Category</h3>
...
      <ul class="categoryUL">
<?php
        $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
        foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
        {
            $name = $child_product_cat->name;
            $slug = $child_product_cat->slug;
            $term_id = $child_product_cat->term_id;
?>
            <li id='categoryLI-<?= $slug ?>'>
              <a id='<?= $term_id ?>' href='#'><?=    $child_product_cat->name?></a>
            </li>
<?php
            // the id is the slug of the subcategory, and the action is performed in the jQuery event
        } // end FOREACH CHILD
?>
        </ul>
...
</div>
```

I keep getting error 400 bad request in the console, but am stumped on how to further debug, as no output from the callback function appears when I echo, alert or console.log.

Comment: What's your `ajax.url` and what are the `term_id` and `action` you specifiy in your post ? Here is the link to the jQuery Post  Doc: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Did you check ajax.url. parameters passed in console. If you've ajax functionality  implemented else where cross check the url,parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

I made a code change to the jQuery.post as follows:
   Original - did not work:

jQuery.post  ( {
      url: ajax.url,
      action: 'show_products',
      term_id: term_id_clicked,
      success: function ( data ) {

to this format, which is now returning with a 200 code:

```
jQuery.post  ( {
  url: ajax.url,
  data : {
     action : 'show_products',
     term_id : term_id_clicked
  },
  success: function ( data ) {
```

BTW, contacted WPEngine and even though the site is in "transferrable" mode, which requires a username and password, this was not the issue.